# AppSync Custom Resolver to count DynamoDB entries

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have a React AppSync app with AWS resources provisioned using the Amplify CLI. I need to fetch the number of entities in one of my tables that contains several thousand entries, without having to fetch the entries themselves. Besides the stupidity of fetching thousands of entities just to count them, I'm also running into the problem that I can't even get all those records in one request anyway. A simple call like this:

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";

const nodeData = await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(
    `query allNodeIds {
      listNodes(limit: 10000) {
        items {
          id
        }
      }
    }`,
    {}
  )
);

const nodeCount = nodeData.data.listNodes.items.length;
```

Causes the following console error:

```
...
errorType: "MappingTemplate"
message: "List size cannot exceed 1000"
```

It seems I need to write a custom query & resolver to count and return the number of entries in the table, but don't know where to start with writing resolvers (in VTL?), where to put them in the project, etc. Any help?

**EDIT**: Wrote a resolver based on one of my other generated resolvers, but it still seems to be capped at 1001 records, though I set the limit to 9999.

**Schema**

```
...
countResponses(filter: ModelResponseFilterInput, limit: Int, nextToken: String): Int
```

**Request Mapping Template**

```
#set( $limit = $util.defaultIfNull($context.args.limit, 9999) )
#set( $ListRequest = {
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "limit": $limit
} )
#if( $context.args.nextToken )
  #set( $ListRequest.nextToken = "$context.args.nextToken" )
#end
#if( $context.args.filter )
  #set( $ListRequest.filter = $util.parseJson("$util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression($ctx.args.filter)") )
#end
#if( !$util.isNull($modelQueryExpression)
                        && !$util.isNullOrEmpty($modelQueryExpression.expression) )
  $util.qr($ListRequest.put("operation", "Query"))
  $util.qr($ListRequest.put("query", $modelQueryExpression))
  #if( !$util.isNull($ctx.args.sortDirection) && $ctx.args.sortDirection == "DESC" )
    #set( $ListRequest.scanIndexForward = false )
  #else
    #set( $ListRequest.scanIndexForward = true )
  #end
#else
  $util.qr($ListRequest.put("operation", "Scan"))
#end
$util.toJson($ListRequest)
```

**Response Mapping Template**

```
## [Start] Determine request authentication mode **
#if( $util.isNullOrEmpty($authMode) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.sub) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.issuer) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.username) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.claims) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.sourceIp) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.defaultAuthStrategy) )
  #set( $authMode = "userPools" )
#end
## [End] Determine request authentication mode **
## [Start] Check authMode and execute owner/group checks **
#if( $authMode == "userPools" )
  ## No Static Group Authorization Rules **


  ## [Start] If not static group authorized, filter items **
  #if( !$isStaticGroupAuthorized )
    #set( $count = 0 )
    #foreach( $item in $ctx.result.items )
      ## No Dynamic Group Authorization Rules **


      ## [Start] Owner Authorization Checks **
      #set( $isLocalOwnerAuthorized = false )
      ## Authorization rule: { allow: owner, ownerField: "owner", identityClaim: "cognito:username" } **
      #set( $allowedOwners0 = $item.owner )
      #set( $identityValue = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("username"), $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:username"), "___xamznone____")) )
      #if( $util.isList($allowedOwners0) )
        #foreach( $allowedOwner in $allowedOwners0 )
          #if( $allowedOwner == $identityValue )
            #set( $isLocalOwnerAuthorized = true )
          #end
        #end
      #end
      #if( $util.isString($allowedOwners0) )
        #if( $allowedOwners0 == $identityValue )
          #set( $isLocalOwnerAuthorized = true )
        #end
      #end
      ## [End] Owner Authorization Checks **


      #if( ($isLocalDynamicGroupAuthorized == true || $isLocalOwnerAuthorized == true) )
        #set( $count = $count + 1)
      #end
    #end
    #set( $ctx = $count )
  #end
  ## [End] If not static group authorized, filter items **
#end
## [End] Check authMode and execute owner/group checks **

$util.toJson($ctx)
```

Comment: Start by writing one GraphQL query in your schema. The next  place to continue to depends on the type of AppSync resolver.  The most popular two types are DynamoDB and Lambda. Simply pick one custom resolver type on this GraphQL transform web page: [custom-resolvers](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql?sdk=js#custom-resolvers) for an example of custom resolvers for both resolver types, DynamoDB or Lambda. FYI, the DynamoDB may benefit from a secondary index, too.  Define the index in the GraphQL schema with @key.

Comment: @starpebble this doesn't fix the issue that I can't perform the count operation on the server side, and thus have to chain requests using `nextToken` until I have fetched all the results -- and THEN count them. I don't want to get all the records 1000 at a time. I want the server to count them and return me an integer.

Comment: I tried writing custom resolvers in the console (I'm using DynamoDB btw), and can successfully return an integer, but it's capped at 1001 records, even though I can see I have many more. I guess this has to do with the DynamoDB "scan" operation limitations. Posting my resolvers above..

Comment: That's an interesting limit, 1001. To both count and to list all ids, I somewhat agree then the custom resolver must have a loop. I don't think the posted vtl will work without a loop in some cases because of limits. Try a lambda resolver.  Put a loop in the lambda resolver to retrieve all list of id's. There are some limits to how many item id's a lambda function can return because of the byte size limits on a lambda function response payload.  If the list byte size has to scale beyond the payload limit then consider a cached file. Kinda feels like scaling is important to this query.

Comment: @starpebble Will give it a try. Don't actually need the IDs, it was my initial attempt at using an existing query to get around having to write a custom resolver. First time working with AWS anything.

Comment: Save money and call DynamoDB::DescribeTable() from an amplify REST API.  DescribeTable will respond with an Item Count estimate and is faster than iterating over a result set when the desired response is simply the item count alone for the entire table.  AppSync is computationally expensive.  Try 'amplify add api' and select REST and have fun!

Comment: I failed to mention that I need to count entities only the current user owns... Not sure there's a way around AppSync with this requirement. But thanks for your help!

Comment: That is interesting, that the response vtl checks the current user ownership. Kinda sounds like the username is a part of the Node item data model schema. Because of search. Keep going with AppSync. Introduce username to the Node entity schema and add one `@key` directive. It'll feel new. Adjust the GraphQL query and add one parameter, 'username.'  Include the username in the mutation to create the Node item.  Or get fast custom query response from ElasticSearch and the `@searchable` directive.  Are you comfortable with ElasticSearch and Lambda?